# Mysql Connector and Dapper System.TypeLoad Exception System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I have this snippet of code, which I'm using in 2 different solutions and it works in one of them, but not in the other.

```
    protected internal static int SomeMethod(string x,string y)
{
    int result;
    using (MySqlConnection connectionMysql = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connectionMysql.Open();
        DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@x", x);
        parameters.Add("@y", y);
        parameters.Add("@z", dbType: DbType.Int16, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        connectionMysql.Execute("SP", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        result = parameters.Get<int>("@z");
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `ConnectionString` is valid and tested through a separate application.

I did not include all the code because it is irrelevant to the question.

The Issue is it throws an Exception at `ConnectionMysql.Open()`

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
> 'System.Diagnostics.Activity' from assembly
> 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.1.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.'

The System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource Version is 7.0.0.2 which is present in the references and is available beside the Project DLL at the Execution Folder.
But for some reason at the run-time it searches for Version 4.0.1.0 as shown in the exception
I checked the references and packages, and System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource V 7.0.0.2, which is the latest Stable Version.

This is a C# Class Library Project, based on.NetFramework 4.8.0

Packages Used

```
> Dapper 
> MySqlConnector 
> EntityFramework
> System.Data.Sqlite
```

All Packages are up to the latest version
I searched for a solution with no luck, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: by the way, the connection string is valid and working in other applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple non-logical trials,
I Uninstalled the Mysql Connector Nuget with its System.Diagnostics Dependancy, Then I installed them again, and everything now works fine.

Comment: More on what caused the issue from the start, `MySqlConnector` uses System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource Version 7.0.0.2, which has a more updated version 8.0.0.0 , which i updated directly through the Nuget manager. That what caused the whole problem